# Application security: Counting days independent of system calendar

Tags: vb.net

I want to add a feature to my trial version of the application.  After first activation, I want to make it limited to 90 days.  But I am concerned about user's changing the date of system hence deceiving my application.
Is there any possibility to make it fool proof in a way that even if user takes the calender back, application expires after 90 days of first activation?  First activation date has been saved in the database.

Thank you very much.
Furqan

Answer (score 3):

In short, no, unless your application can run 24/7 and only allows itself to be started once. Even then, there'd be ways to subvert it.

@SB.101's answer is a way of checking for very simple date fiddling. It won't catch sophisticated cheats who know you're doing that and just keep setting the date to something sneaky that fools your checks. It will also annoy the odd few users who change the date on their system legitimately.

Pinging a server of yours over the internet to get the date would help, but is still able to be spoofed, and now annoys your users by forcing them to be connected to the internet (unless your application already needs that).

There is no sure-fire way of doing this. It is theoretically impossible. Remember that no matter how clever you are at checking whether the trial period has elapsed, a user can always modify or delete the recording of when the trial started!

I would advise you to just do something quick and simple, and rely on the fact that the small percentage of people who are both able to subvert your trial limitation and willing to bother doing so are unlikely to purchase the full version of your application anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can also save last run date in DB and can compare that to system date if that is newer that system date then you are deceived!

or

If you can use HTTP then can query time servers for current date time

Comment: Yes but in this case I can either shut down the application or issue a warning.  Can't keep track how many idle days have elapsed.